# I would like to access Android's internal shared storage /Movies/Tickets/movie.jpg in the following environment

Tags: android, xamarin

I would like to access Android's internal shared storage /Movies/Tickets/movie.jpg in the following environment.

NET Standard 2.0
Target Android (Android12.0 API31-S)
OPPO CPH2199 (Android12.0 API31)
Visual Studio 2022 17.3.0
C# (C#)

https://learn.microsoft.com/ja-jp/xamarin/android/platform/files/
I'm doing a lot of things as follows, referring to

```
            var basePath = Xamarin.Essentials.FileSystem.AppDataDirectory;
            var video = System.Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.MyVideos);
            var domucent = System.Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments);
            var videoMother = Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.MyVideos));
            var videoGrandMother = Path.GetDirectoryName(videoMother);
            var videoGrand2Mother = Path.GetDirectoryName(videoGrandMother);
            var videoTickets = Directory.GetFiles(videoMother, "*. *g", SearchOption.AllDirectories).ToList();
            var videoTickets2 = Directory.GetFiles(videoGrandMother, "*. *g", SearchOption.AllDirectories).ToList();
            var grandFolders = Directory.GetDirectories(videoGrandMother);
            var videoFolders = Directory.GetDirectories(video);
```

etc., but I cannot find the /Movies folder.
How can I access Android's internal shared storage /Movies/Tickets/movie.jpg?
[image]

Comment: you need to root your device

Comment: Thank you comment Jason. How can I root my device?

Comment: We do not recommend rooting your phone, which can easily cause information leakage. However, if you still want to root your device, you can find more information about this in  your browser.